# ¿Cuál es la respuesta correcta para "Si hubiéramos estudiado todo el temario, no _______ haciendo el examen extraordinario"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

En el examen [Ceneval EXANI-II](http://www.ceneval.edu.mx/ceneval-web/content.do?page=1738) que se aplica a los aspirantes para licenciatura viene esta pregunta:

> Si hubiéramos estudiado todo el temario, no _______ haciendo el examen
>   extraordinario.
>
> - A) estuviéramos
> - B) estuviésemos
> - C) estaríamos
> - D) estaremos

¿Cuál es la respuesta correcta y por qué? La A, B y C parecen correctas pero la única que corresponde a la misma conjugación que "hubiéramos" es "estuviéramos" la A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta correcta es la C. Se trata de un caso común de [condicional simple](https://espanol.lingolia.com/es/gramatica/tiempos/condicional-simple).

> Si hubiéramos estudiado *(en su momento)* todo el temario, no estaríamos *(ahora)* haciendo el examen extraordinario *(también conocido como examen de recuperación)*.

En cualquier caso, como pista/truco para exámenes tipo test, la A y la B puedes descartarlas puesto que se trata en realidad de la misma respuesta (son las dos formas del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo del verbo estar).

Comment: Interesante el truco que mencionas. En realidad he oido a muchos nativos decirlo de la forma A y B por eso la confusión.

Comment: A lo largo de la historia de la lengua española (incluyendo el tiempo medieval), los hablantes han ido sustituyendo la forma del pluscuamperfecto simple del indicativo (hoy día la forma predominante del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo) por el condicional.  De ahí, puede que algunos usen las formas con -se como tipo de sobrecorrección.

Comment: Por lo tanto de lo arriba, he visto en al menos un par de libros de gramática aceptando la forma -se en la parte irreal conjunto con la forma -ra en la parte condicional.  No sé si la RAE lo considera parte del habla culta, habría que investigar.

Comment: Ojo: es un condicional simple, no compuesto. El compuesto sería *habríamos estado*, que en este caso es incorrecto.

Answer (score 3):

Para mí la única que suena bien es la opción C:

> Si hubiéramos estudiado todo el temario, no **estaríamos** haciendo el examen extraordinario.

Parece que este condicional explica una situación irreal en el pasado (un hecho que no se ha producido) y por tanto usa  el pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo en la subordinada y el condicional o condicional perfecto de indicativo en la oración principal.

> Si hubiéramos estudiado todo el temario, habríamos aprobado.
>
> Si hubiéramos aprobado todo, ahora estaríamos en la playa.
>
> Si hubiéramos estudiado todo el temario, no habríamos tenido que hacer otro examen.
>
> Si hubiésemos construido un bunker, ahora estaríamos a salvo.
>
> Si hubiésemos invertido en Google al comienzo de su carrera, ahora seríamos ricos
>
> Si tuviésemos el otro libro sabríamos las respuestas